# Matrix and differomorphism.

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Say I have a positive-definite (in particular invertible) matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose also that $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded domain with smooth boundary. Is the linear map
$$
T:U\to T(U),\quad x\mapsto Ax
$$
a diffeomorphism on $U$?

I feel like the answer should be yes but I wanted to make sure (by the way, this is not a homework problem). Could anyone confirm my hypothesis? Or am I wrong to assume this?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. The differential of a linear map is just that linear map itself. So this differential is invertible everywhere. It is $C^\infty$ because the coordinates in the image are polynomials.

Comment: @user25959 Thanks for the reply!